HTML / CSS Calc / Flexbox positioning problem
I have been trying to make a page which has 3 horizontal sections, with content in the middle section that overlaps the sections above and below it.  The content in the middle section is arranged using flex.
I attempted to set the position of the mid section content 100px above and using calc to set the height of the content to be 100% - 200px but not getting the desired effect.
This is what I am trying for:

And this is the HTML/CSS I am using:


* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.sectionClass {
  min-height: 300px;
}

#section01 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 300px;
}

#section02 {
  background-color: brown;
}

#section03 {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 300px;
}

#mainContainer {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  height: calc(100% - 200px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.sectionItem {
  max-width: calc(100% / 6);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.sectionItem p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
<body>
  <div id="section01" class="sectionClass"></div>
  <div id="section02" class="sectionClass">
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section03" class="sectionClass"></div>
</body>



Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?
Thanks in advance.x
This is what I am getting:


Not sure why calc would get involved here to begin with, are there additional restrictions you did not explicitly mention? Like, all three sections together should not exceed the viewport height? So far; I think your approach of trying to do anything with the main container, should probably be replaced with a negative margin-top and -bottom on the 2nd section.

When you say "overlap", will sections 1 and 3 have any content of their own, or are they purely to provide space around section 2?

I used grid instead of flexbox for this exemple but you can do what you want with a absolute ::after.  Like this


:root {
  --card-width: 200px;
  --card-height: 300px;
}

.cardparent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(var(--card-width), 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, var(--card-height));
  gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.cardparent::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - var(--card-height));
  top: calc(var(--card-height) / 2);
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(30, 66, 13, 0.5);
}

.card {
  background-color: #0D2840;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* 
For this snippet only 
*/

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0
}

section {
  min-height: 50dvh;
}

#sec1 {
  background-color: #DCE8F2;
}

#sec2 {
  background-color: #80A2BF;
  padding: 20px;
}

#sec3 {
  background-color: #54728C;
}
<section id="sec1">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
</section>
<section id="sec2" class="cardparent">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>

</section>
<section id="sec3">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
</section>




What about a gradient background?


* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.sectionClass {
  min-height: 300px;
}

#section01 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 300px;
}

#section02 {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, aquamarine 15%, brown 15%, brown 85%, purple 85%);
}

#section03 {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 300px;
}

#mainContainer {
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
  gap: 1em;
}

.sectionItem {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sectionItem p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
<body>
  <div id="section01" class="sectionClass"></div>
  <div id="section02" class="sectionClass">
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionItem">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section03" class="sectionClass"></div>
</body>




Try removing the
#section03{
    background-color: purple;
    height: 300px; <-
}

if this doesnt work , try adding a overflow:hidden in section03 , or you can try with section 2  , but to make it with margins- , if that doesnt help feel free to email me.
